# How do I show signed in users information?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to understand how this works without adding Roles, but maybe it won't. I'm following along with Microsofts tutorial [about protecting user data with Authorize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1) but I am still having trouble understanding this without roles.

In my database, I have the AspNet identity tables and a few custom tables. Is there a way to show the signed-in users' data to them from the custom table? I have look on here but I'm probably not searching for the right thing.

I have tried getting the user email from context and checking userManager for that email if it's found then pushing it to a list but that just returns null.

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            var employee = from e in Context.EmpInfo
                select e;
           
            var currentUserId = UserManager.GetUserId(User);

            employee = employee.Where(e =>e.OwnerId == currentUserId);
            
            EmpInfo = await employee.ToListAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code to check the actual value of `UserManager.GetUserId(User);`? Does it return null?

Comment: Yes the value is being placed in UserManager. After looking closer at the Microsoft example, they were setting OwnerId to the admin role ID. Not the solution I’m looking for. I guess I would need to compare email against email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to show the signed-in users' data to them from the custom table?

> they were setting OwnerId to the admin role ID

In `AspNetUsers` table as below, `Id` of user is a primary key. To implement one-to-one relationships between `AspNetUsers` and `Employee`, you can store corresponding `AspNetUsers.Id` in `OwnerId` of specific employee, then you can get detailed employee information based on retrieved User's Id.

[image]

> I guess I would need to compare email against email?

If you persist email information in both `AspNetUsers` and `Employee` tables, getting corresponding employee information by comparing email as you mentioned could be an alternative approach.

```
//find user and get user's email
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var user_email = user?.Email.ToString();

//...
//query employee table with retrieved user_email 
//code logic here...
```

Besides, please note that if you do not configure [`RequireUniqueEmail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1#user) in your ASP.NET Core Identity system, users might be with duplicate emails.

Comment: I like the idea of linking the actual user.Id to OwnerId. So I'm testing this out but I'm not sure how to push that information over. It will be a prepopulated database table so that value will be null until then. Is there a way to set it during registration? Perhaps I'll make it a separate question and link it here later.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63586662/how-can-i-add-user-id-value-to-custom-userid-during-registration