# How can I add User.Id value to Custom.UserId during registration?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I will have a prepopulated Database that will have information pushed to it from another server. One of the columns will be UserId and will have a one to one relationship with ApplicationUser. I am using Identity Core for security.

How do I collect the AspNetUser.Id during the registration process and push it to the other table EmpProflie.UserId value?

I think during OnPostAsync's `if(result.Succeeded)` I should be able to get the value of the AspNetUser Id by calling the following code somewhere after the email confirmation is sent.
**Error obviously on var userId**

```
var aspUserId = _userManager.Users.Select(e=>e.Id);
var userId = _context.EmpProfile.Add(aspUserId).Entity.UserId;
```

I'm not sure how to push that value to the current user who is registering
so that it's assigned off the bat. `_context.EmpProfile.UserId?????`

Here is the full Method:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            var isInDb =
                _context.EmpProfile.Any(e => e.Email.ToLower() == Input.Email.ToLower());

            if (ModelState.IsValid && isInDb)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    var userId = _userManager.Users.Select(e => e.Id);
                    var userId = _context.EmpProfile.Add(aspUserId).Entity.UserId; <--- ERROR

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }


                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried the following but I'm not sure how to set just the UserId value.

Like user @Fei Han suggested below, I found how to get aspnet User.Id looking through stackoverflow last night.

```
var aspUserId = user.Id;
                    if (aspUserId != null)
                    {
                        var ownerId = new EmpInfo
                        {
                            UserId = aspUserId
                        };
                        _context.Update(ownerId);
                        _context.SaveChanges();
                    }
```

However, this is overwriting all of my existing data when I set the value. I **am** getting the UserId to value set properly though. I just can't figure out as of yet how to only set/update the ONE property without overwriting all the others.

Comment: `how to only set/update the ONE property without overwriting all the others` Hi @KentHub, please check my new update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I collect the AspNetUser.Id during the registration process and push it to the other table EmpProflie.UserId value?

If you debug the code, you would find that the `Id` property is initialized to form a new GUID string value while you create a new IdentityUser object, like below.

[image]

So you can modify the code as below to get new user's Id, then store or update to your EmpProfile table.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //get new registered user's id
            var user_id = user.Id;

            //store or update with new reger user's id in EmpProfile table
            //...
```

***Update:***

> how to only set/update the ONE property without overwriting all the others

To update EmpProfile UserId with aspUserId and persist to the database, you can refer to the following code snippet.

```
var Emp = _context.EmpProfile.Where(e => e.Email.ToLower() == Input.Email.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();

if (ModelState.IsValid && Emp != null)
{
    var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        //get new registered user's id
        var aspUserId = user.Id;

        //store or update with new reger user's id in EmpProfile table
        //...

        if (aspUserId != null)
        {
            Emp.UserId = aspUserId;

            //By default, queries that return entity types are tracking
            //can make changes to those entity instances and have those changes persisted by SaveChanges()

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Besides, you can check [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) to know about "Tracking vs. No-Tracking Queries".

Comment: Thanks Fei, I had tried something similar to that but whatever I did (I think select with the user PK) was not working. I also ended up with sever errors in my current setup so I wiped my Navigation Relationships and this performs just as I hoped. Thanks again for all of your help!